# harden php sessions - comparison error

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to harden up my sessions and found the code below. My question is this line `isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`.

When I echo out the comparison the IP numbers are the same yet that line of code compares the two to be different. If i compare it as `!=` then the comparison works. Why is that? Shouldn't both values be totally identical? Any suggestions how can I fix it so they are `===`?

```
ini_set('session.cookie_httponly', true);
session_start();
if ( isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) === false ) {
    $_SESSION['last_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
if ( isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) {
    echo $_SESSION['last_ip'] . ' / ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // the output is identical
}
```

Comment: Is the $_SESSION['last_ip'] manipulated in any way? Like added slashes or extra whitespace?

Comment: @PRPGFerret no,  its exactly as shown.  (updated the question)

Comment: There has to be SOME sort of difference if the comparison works, but identical isn't. maybe try trimming both values?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) !== $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) {
```

You're checking to see if one is set and the other matches that boolean value. Remove the `isset`.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, i'll be solving this with AND operator in the IF sequence such as:

```
if ( isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) && $_SESSIOn['last_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ) {
```

Does this helps?

Comment: from this line `isset($_SESSION['last_ip']) && $_SESSIOn['last_ip'] != $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ` is this saying that if session last_ip did not exist then the comparison would not happen?